# Calculate the average sale for each month in excel 2013 pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a large chunk of sales data with (some columns removed for clarity purposes):

> Order Id, Order Date, Product, Amount, Product Price, Row total cost, Order total cost

A specific order can, as you may see, be divided over multiple rows - were order id, order date and order total is the same on each row. The "row total cost" contains the price for a specific amount of a specific product in the order.

It's not the best way to store data - I know...

Any ways. What I would like to do is to calculate the average sales value for each month. For example - total sales in sep 2012 is $1000, and in sep 2013 it's $500. The average sale for september would be 1000 + 500 / 2 = $750.

This I would like to present in a pivot table and pivot chart.

What I'm stuck with is an average sales value compared to the grand total (sep 2013 compared with all month of 2013 and 2012). I believe I need to group or filter my average calculation - but can't figure out how to do that.

Any help is much appreciated. Using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Is the challenge caused by the "Order Total Cost" column containing repeats, and hence when you get average of that column it is not accurate?

If I assume that the columns you list are headings in row 1 and that data starts in row 2, then add a column headed `Real order total` with the formula `=if(A2=A1,"",G2)` in cell H2. Copy that down and it will give the order total just once for each order. Then base your average or pivot table on col H rather than G.